# Is there a difference measure that is insensitive to shifts?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, waveform-similarity

I'm trying to figure out a difference measure that is relatively insensitive to time shifts.

I have tried DTW (dynamic time warping.)

This is the result:

[image: below]

The signals on the left are clearly more similar than the signals on the right yet due to time shifts I get larger normed difference for the left than for the right.

Is there any measure/technique I can use to overcome this? I will investigate the frequency domain but I wanted this community's opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You could upsample your data to increase the sample density and perform a cross correlation between the two signals to determine the time-offset. Then shift the signals by the offset and the difference as you already are.

Answer (score 1):

I see two main options: data transformation or extensive search.

First, the amplitude spectrum from the Fourier transform is invariant to integer shifts in the signal, and weakly sensitive to non-integer shifts in practice. Other transforms possess similar features. You can from here build a measure based only on certain parts or features of the transform. Other transforms are called shift-invariant, or nearly shift-invariant: they are more equivariant, but can be used as well.

Second, when the signals are not atrociously long, you can afford to measure differences between one ($s_1(k)$) and all shifts of the other $s_2(k-l)$. You can even use sub-integer signs.

Finally, both approaches can be combined. In your case, I would go for the basic Fourier approach, as the signals look quite alike.

Answer (score 0):

Time scattering by design yields timeshift-invariant representations, with control over amount of desired invariance. An advantage is ability to compare within a frequency range of interest rather than in entirety.

It's the continuous wavelet transform, followed by modulus and lowpass filtering; [nice lecture](https://youtu.be/4eyUReyIPXg).

[image]

```
Distance with T=2048: 0.022988
Distance with T=1024: 0.172749
Distance with T=512:  0.415810
```

---

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
from kymatio import Scattering1D
from kymatio.visuals import plot, imshow

def _l2(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(x)**2))

def l2(x0, x1):
    """Squared relative distance measure."""
    return _l2(x1 - x0) / _l2(x0)

#%% configure scattering & signal ############################################
N = 4096
Q = 16
J = 9
width = N//8
shift = N//8
# set amounts of invariance
T0, T1 = N//4, N//8
freq_fracs = (4, 8, 16, 32)

#%% make signal & shifted ####################################################
window = scipy.signal.tukey(width, alpha=0.5)
window = np.pad(window, (N - width) // 2)
t  = np.linspace(0, 1, N, endpoint=False)
x  = np.sum([np.cos(2*np.pi * N/ff * t) for ff in freq_fracs], axis=0
            ) * window
xs = np.roll(x, shift)

#%% visualize signals ########################################################
plot(x,  title="x, original",    show=1)
plot(xs, title="x, timeshifted", show=1)

#%% make scattering objects ##################################################
max_order = 1  # 2 yields better results but requires understanding; see docs
kw = dict(J=J, Q=Q, shape=N, average=1, out_type="array", pad_mode="zero",
          max_pad_factor=1, frontend='numpy', max_order=1)
ts0 = Scattering1D(T=T0, **kw)
ts1 = Scattering1D(T=T1, **kw)
#%% scatter 
out0_x  = ts0.scattering(x)
out0_xs = ts0.scattering(xs)
out1_x  = ts1.scattering(x)
out1_xs = ts1.scattering(xs)

#%% compute & print distances ################################################
l2_0 = l2(out0_x, out0_xs)
l2_1 = l2(out1_x, out1_xs)
print("Distance with T={}: {:.6f}".format(T0, l2_0))
print("Distance with T={}: {:.6f}".format(T1, l2_1))

#%% visualize coeffs
imshow(out0_x,  title="scattering(x), original    | T=%s" % T0, abs=1)
imshow(out0_xs, title="scattering(x), timeshifted | T=%s" % T0, abs=1)
imshow(out1_x,  title="scattering(x), original    | T=%s" % T1, abs=1)
imshow(out1_xs, title="scattering(x), timeshifted | T=%s" % T1, abs=1)
```